# Directory permissions on Ubuntu Server 10.04 LTS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, samba

I have set up a second drive on Ubuntu Server. The directory displays correctly but Windows users cannot write or create files on the directory. I have Samba set up so Windows can access the drives. here is the last bit of my `/etc/samba/smb.conf`

```
[personeel]
path = /media/windows
browsable = yes
guest ok = yes
writable = yes
read only = no
create mask = 0775
directory mask = 0775
```

I want the directory to be shared with writable permissions to everyone who can access the Ubuntu Server.

I have tried sudo chmod but to no success.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you allow guests to access this share. So I believe you want to allow write access as well to everyone. If this is the case force Samba to act as a specific user and group for read / write access to this share:

```
[personeel]
path = /media/windows
browsable = yes
guest ok = yes
writable = yes
create mask = 0660
directory mask = 0770
force group = usergroup
force user = user
```

You should replace **usergroup** and **user** by the correct user group and user of your Linux box. Additionally take care to grant write access to this user/user group for the folder /media/windows :

```
# set owner of folder and all contents to user and usergroup
chown -R user:usergroup /media/windows

# find all directories in this folder and do a chmod 0777
find /media/windows -type d -exec chmod 0770 {} \;

# find all files in this folder and do a chmod 0660
find /media/windows -type f -exec chmod 0660 {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

> chmod -Rf 777 /media/windows
>
> chown -Rf root:users /media/windows

to create an accessable file you must config the /etc/exports